# Multiple model forms with (foreign key) in multiple pages. Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

This is my first Question ever on StackOverflow, so bear with me for my mistakes.

Now, to the question!

I am currently making website in django and It has multiple models which are linked to one parent model. Now I want to create a multiple page form to include all this models. How to do that???

here's problem in detail:

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    first_name = odels.CharField(
        max_length=255, validators=ONLY_LETTERS_VALIDATOR)
    last_name = odels.CharField(
        max_length=255, validators=ONLY_LETTERS_VALIDATOR)

    # And some other fields

class YMHTMobile(models.Model):

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)

    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=ONLY_DIGITS_VALIDATOR)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.mobile

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mobile Details'

# some more models with foreign key as profile
```

Now I want to create a Multiple page form with all these models(like one model form in one page and click next for another form)

How do I do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) contrib app.

**UPDATE:** Form Wizard was moved from django 1.8 to separate project - [Django Form Tools](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html).

Comment: Isn't it for forms with same models??

Comment: No. Don't confuse it with formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Might you want to add some explanation to that answer?

Comment: Added update about Django Form Tools - https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html